# VNRecognizeTextRequest unable to recognise text scanned in landscape mode

Tags: swift, ios13, ios-vision, vndocumentcameraviewcontroller

I'm using `VNDocumentCameraViewController` to scan document and `VNRecognizeTextRequest` to detect the text. It works only if the document is scanned in portrait mode. It landscape mode it fails. I could pass the orientation in `VNImageRequestHandler` but that would fail for portrait scans. 
Again, if I try to check the scanned image orientation it's always `.up`. So I can't even manipulate the image. Anybody has any idea how to fix this orientation issue? I'm using below code.

```
@IBAction func scanTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    allComponents = [Component]()
    let documentCameraViewController = VNDocumentCameraViewController()

    documentCameraViewController.delegate = self
    self.present(documentCameraViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func documentCameraViewController(_ controller: VNDocumentCameraViewController, didFinishWith scan: VNDocumentCameraScan) {
    let image = scan.imageOfPage(at: scan.pageCount-1)


    let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: image.cgImage!, options: [:])
    do {
        try handler.perform([textRecognitionRequest])
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    controller.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was solved when I've enabled landscape device orientation.